# How to set Generic search on more than one item in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am using a search functionality where I search the leave from **LeaveType** and it works fine but I want to search for **Status** also,  the item contains Status.
How the search function will work on both **LeaveType** and **Status**.
What i have tried :

```
const itemData = item.LeaveType ? item.LeaveType.toUpperCase() : ''.toUpperCase() || item.Status ? item.Status.toUpperCase() : ''.toUpperCase();
```

I am using this function

```
SearchFilterFunction(value) {
    const newData = this.state.display.filter(function(item) {
        const itemData = item.LeaveType ? item.LeaveType.toUpperCase() : ''.toUpperCase();
      const textData = value.toUpperCase();
      return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
    });
    this.setState({
      response: newData,
      value: value,
    });
  }
```

can anyone know what wrong I'm doing or what is missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code works for me

```
 SearchFilterFunction(value) {
    const newData = this.state.display.filter(function(item) {
      //const itemData = item.LeaveType || item.Status ? item.LeaveType.toUpperCase() || item.Status.toUpperCase() : ''.toUpperCase() || ''.toUpperCase();
        const leavetypeData = item.LeaveType ? item.LeaveType.toUpperCase() : ''.toUpperCase();
        const statusData = item.Status ? item.Status.toUpperCase() : ''.toUpperCase();
        const stData = item.StartDate ? (moment(item.StartDate).format("dd MMM yyyy")) : '';
        const edData = item.EndDate ?  (moment(item.EndDate).format("dd MMM yyyy")) : '';
        const reasonData = item.Reason ?  (item.Reason).toUpperCase() : '';
      const textData = value.toUpperCase();
      return (leavetypeData.indexOf(textData) > -1 ||  statusData.indexOf(textData) > -1 || stData.toUpperCase().indexOf(textData) > -1 
      ||  edData.toUpperCase().indexOf(textData) > -1 ||  reasonData.indexOf(textData) > -1);
    });
    this.setState({
      response: newData,
      value: value,
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my function. Its work 3 param search.

```html
searchFilter = text => {
  const newData = this.state.allContacts.filter(item => {
   const listItem = `${item.name.first.toLowerCase()} ${item.name.last.toLowerCase()} ${item.location.state.toLowerCase()}`;

   return listItem.indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  });

  this.setState({
   contacts: newData,
  });
 };
```